# Android - Non-programmatically Change back button based on language (English and Arabic)

Tags: android, icons, multilingual

Is there any way to change the direction of back button based on language other than programmatically?

[image: I want this icon for English]

I want this icon for English

[image: I want this one for Arabic]

I want this one for Arabic

Comment: add support rtl=true in menifest

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true" is already added. Is there anything missed to flip back button?

Comment: is above image is vector image?

Comment: No the above one is a png image

Comment: try with vector image it supports RTL

Answer (score 10):

You can use by Vector Drawable,

just set **android:autoMirrored="true"** it will flip the image

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="8dp"
android:height="18dp"
android:autoMirrored="true"
android:viewportHeight="15.0"
android:viewportWidth="9.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:pathData="M8,1l-7,6.5l7,6.5"
    android:strokeColor="#6D6D6D"
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeWidth="2" />
```

Comment: this works, but what about png(s) drawables?

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

- make sure to enable the RTL flag in the manifest `android:supportsRtl="true"`
- make sure you don't have `android:layoutDirection="ltr/rtl"` in your layout or parent layouts (activity of fragments) - this could mess things up

  - or add `android:layoutDirection="local"` if something looked weird

Now for icons, there are 2 cases

## 1. Vectors

if you have your icon as vector XML i.e. imported from SVG
on the import screen just toggle the Enable auto mirroring for RTL layout
[image: Enable auto mirroring for RTL layout]
or if you already have it In your project, go to the XML file and add this line `android:autoMirrored="true"` to the parent `vector` tag

[image: android:autoMirrored="true"]

---

## 2. PNGs with multiple sizes

if you have it as PNG with multiple sizes, you should then get another PNG image for the RTL layouts yourself, but then you need to add the new RTL images/icons to `drawable-[layout direction/language]-[size]` directory e.g. `drawable-ar-hdpi` this way the icon will be for hdpi screen-size and for the Arabic language
make sure to follow the same order cuz it won't work otherwise

[image: drawable-[layout direction/language]-[size]]